# How can I use `catchfile` package to gobble first characters on a line

Tags: input, latex3, expl3, catchfile

When using the `fancyvrb` environment `Verbatim`, you can gobble the first `n` characters of each line before printing it out.  I'd like to be able to do something similar, but not via verbatim.

In the following MWE, I would like to read in the file:

```
    \textbf{This is the first line.}
%%  \textbf{This is the second line.}
```

and have LaTeX process it as though it'd been passed a file:

```
\textbf{This is the first line.}
\textbf{This is the second line.}
```

Here's an example of what I've tried, but it doesn't work as hoped:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{aetesting}
    \textbf{This is the first line.}
%%  \textbf{This is the second line.}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{catchfile}
\def\gobblefirst#1#2#3#4{}
\def\mysetup{\let\do\gobblefirst\dospecials}
\CatchFileDef{\aemyfile}{aetesting}\mysetup
\begin{document}

\aemyfile

\end{document}
```

**UPDATE**

I can almost get this to work (without `catchfile`)

```
\begin{filecontents*}{aetesting}
  The character of the First Caesar has perhaps never been worse
  appreciated than by him who in one sense described it best; that is,

  \textbf{This is the first line.}\par
%%  \textbf{This is the second line.}


%%  Great as Caesar was by the benefit of his original nature, there can be
  no doubt that he, like others, owed something to circumstances; and
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter

\newread\file
\newcommand\aeomit[2]{}
\newcommand\myaccumulatedfile{}
\newcommand*\aegobbleinput[1]{%
  \IfFileExists{#1}{%
    \openin\file #1
    \begingroup
    \endlinechar\newlinechar
    \loop\unless\ifeof\file
      \obeyspaces
      \readline\file to\foo
      \edef\myaccumulatedfile{\myaccumulatedfile\expandafter\@gobbletwo\foo\relax\relax}%%
    \repeat
    \closein\file
    \expandafter\endgroup
    \scantokens\expandafter{\myaccumulatedfile}
  }{%
    \errmessage{File `#1' doesn't exist!}%
  }%
}

\makeatother
\begin{document}

Try:

\aegobbleinput{aetesting}

\end{document}
```

The problem is that leading spaces are ignored and I don't want them ignored.
Also my line break before `\textbf{This is the first line.}` is no longer properly treated as a paragraph break.  :(

**Further update**

Thinking I might try this in LaTeX3, I run into even more troubles.

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\ior_new:N \g_ae_fh_ior
\tl_new:N  \l_ae_fh_line_tl

\cs_new:Npn \__ae_gobble:n #1 
  {
    \file_if_exist:nTF { \__ae_open:n { #1 } }
                       { \typeout{no file!}  }
  }

\cs_new:Npn \__ae_open:n #1
  {
    \ior_open:Nn           \g_ae_fh_ior { #1 }
    \ior_str_map_inline:Nn \g_ae_fh_ior { \tl_gput_right:Nn \l_ae_fh_line_tl {##1 \par}}
    \ior_close:N           \g_ae_fh_ior
  }

\NewDocumentCommand{\aegobbleinput}{m}
    {
      \__ae_gobble:n {#1}
    }

\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Here I'm not even trying to truncate anything.  But I can't get LaTeX to read the file.  I get one of two errors with this code.  When I try to use the `inline` map, I get the error

```
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \l__file_internal_name_tl.
<to be read again> 
                   1
l.6 \aegobbleinput{aetesting.tex}

?
```

If I get rid of that line, even though getting rid of it should result in nothing getting parsed, I get the error message

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! LaTeX error: "kernel/space-in-file-name"
! 
! Space in file name '\ior_open:Nn \g_ae_fh_ior {aetesting.tex}\ior_close:N
! \g_ae_fh_ior '.
! 
! See the LaTeX3 documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  

l.6 \aegobbleinput{aetesting.tex}

?
```

which makes absolutely no sense to me particularly because I'm very closely following the example as posted [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60983/22413).

Comment: In your `expl3` definition, you are missing the file name argument for `\file_if_exist:nTF`, hence the error.

Comment: Your `\let\do\gobblefirst\dospecials` is strange as the meaning of `\dospecials` is `macro:->\do \ \do \\\do \{\do \}\do \$\do \&\do \#\do \^\do \_\do \%\do \~`. But I am not familiar with `\CatchFileDef` so perhaps something else happens.

Comment: @jfbu I'm mucking around in the dark here.  I apparently don't understand much of anything about these commands.  They're certainly not working as I think they should.  And what I'm reading in the documentation isn't really helping me.  For example, in the `eTeX` documentation there are only 2 or 3 lines of explanation about `\readline`.  I really feel in the dark.

Comment: Perhaps I did not explain that my proposed answer does not treat line by line: this is handed over to TeX input  process, via the possibility to let the `end of line` act to suppress the first characters of the next line. `TeX by Topic` has some explanations about either reading line by line or inputting in one go a file. And `eTeX` has added stuff such as `\everyeof`. `\readline` seems to be for some sort of verbatim input, I am not familiar with its use, having only some limited experience with `scantokens` for example.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a naive attempt, certainly not foolproof. Forgot to say it does not use the `catchfile` package. The file is not input verbatim but each non-empty line must have at least four initial characters, which are treated verbatim and ignored.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{aetesting}
    \textbf{This is the first line.}
%%  \textbf{This is the second line.}
^_^_End of lines in the input file get converted into spaces, 
    except if followed by an empty line. 

$~\\This follows an empty line in the input.



&&& This follows sucessive empty lines in the input.
\end{filecontents*}

    \makeatletter
\long\def\@gobblethree#1#2#3{}
\long\def\aeafterfi #1#2\fi{\fi #1}

\begingroup
    \catcode1=\active
    \gdef^^A{\begingroup\let\do\@makeother\dospecials\aeaux }
    \gdef\aeaux #1{\ifx #1^^A\aeafterfi{\endgroup\par^^A}%
                    \else   \aeafterfi{ \expandafter\endgroup\@gobblethree}\fi}
\endgroup
    \makeatother

\newcommand*\aeinput [1]{%
    \begingroup
     \endlinechar1
     \catcode1=\active
     \everyeof{\relax\relax\relax\relax}%
     \InputIfFileExists 
         {#1}{}%
         {File `#1' doesn't exist!}% (or using \errmessage)
    \endgroup
}

% character with ascii code 1 made invalid
% apart from its use in \aeinput 
\catcode1=15

\begin{document}

\aeinput{aetesting}

\aeinput{aetesting2} % attempt to input a non-existent file

\aeinput{aetesting} % inputting one more time

\end{document}
```

[image: aeinput]

Comment: Can you explain at all what this is doing?  Two things in particular make no sense to me:  (1) `\gdef^^A`.  What is this?  (2) How does `\@gobblethree` ever get ahold of a line of input?  As far as I can tel you input a file, but nothing gets passed to your line processing commands.

Comment: The (non-printable) character with 8bit ascii code `1`, which can be input to `TeX` as `^^A` (`A` has ascii code 65, and 1=65-64) is made active, and used as `end of line character` when the file is input. In my initial version it gobbled the next four characters, in the posted version this is a bit more complicated as I wanted to allow empty lines in the input to serve as paragraph break. You said you didn't want verbatim input, and here the only things treated `verbatim' (and suppressed) are the first four characters of each non-empty line. Non-empty lines must have at least 4 characters.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure how you intend to use this, so you may need to tell me what to change.  What I did was to print out the first line of the file, as is.  For all subsequent lines, I gobbled two tokens and then output them.

Here's an approach not using `catchfile`.

If the input file `myfile.tex` is

```
\textbf{This is the first line.}
%%  \textbf{This is the second line.}
123456789
```

Then this code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{readarray}
\makeatletter
%GOBBLE COMMANDS, UP TO 8 BYTES
\newcommand\gobblei{\@gobble}
\newcommand\gobbleii{\@gobbletwo}
\newcommand\gobbleiii{\expandafter\@gobble\@gobbletwo}
\newcommand\gobbleiv{\expandafter\@gobbletwo\@gobbletwo}
\newcommand\gobblev{\expandafter\gobbleiii\@gobbletwo}
\newcommand\gobblevi{\expandafter\gobbleiv\@gobbletwo}
\newcommand\gobblevii{\expandafter\gobblev\@gobbletwo}
\newcommand\gobbleviii{\expandafter\gobblevi\@gobbletwo}
\newcounter{index}
\newcounter{gobbleindex}
\catcode`\%=12
\catcode`\|=14
\newcommand\gobblechars[2]{|
\catcode`\%=12
\catcode`\|=14
  \setcounter{gobbleindex}{#2}
  \readdef{#1}{\tmp}|
  \setcounter{index}{1}|
  \showrecord{1}\\|
  \whiledo{\value{index} < \nrows}{|
    \stepcounter{index}|
    \protected@edef\myrecord{\csname record\roman{index}\endcsname}|
    \def\mygobble{\csname gobble\roman{gobbleindex}\endcsname}|
    \expandafter\mygobble\myrecord|
  \\}|
\catcode`\|=12
\catcode`\%=14
}
\catcode`\|=12
\catcode`\%=14
\makeatother

\parindent 0in
\begin{document}
\gobblei    123456789\\
\gobbleii   123456789\\
\gobbleiii  123456789\\
\gobbleiv   123456789\\
\gobblev    123456789\\
\gobblevi   123456789\\
\gobblevii  123456789\\
\gobbleviii 123456789

\gobblechars{myfile.tex}{2}
\end{document}
```

produces this output:

[image]

At this point, the gobble extent is limited to eight tokens, but that could be manually extended (not quite sure how to automate that extension, if needed).  Incidentally, I made `|` the comment character for the processing of the external file.  That can be changed, obviously.