# Errors produces when using `\readline`

Tags: input, e-tex

This question, while related to [this earlier question of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/125986/22413), is less about removing content from the beginning of each line and more about how to preprocess lines of a file as it is read in.

Here is the file I want to preprocess:

```
  The character of the First Caesar has perhaps never been worse
  appreciated than by him who in one sense described it best; that is,

  \textbf{This is the first line.}\par
*  \textbf{This is the second line.}
*
*
*  Great as Caesar was by the benefit of his original nature, there can be
  no doubt that he, like others, owed something to circumstances; and
```

The basic idea is that somewhere I have a boolean set which determines how to process the lines that begin with `*`.  If the boolean is false, these lines are ignored:  as if they had been commented out.  If the boolean is true, then these lines are processed as though they did not start with a star.
In this MWE I don't have any booleans.  This MWE is supposed to represent how things will be processed had the boolean been set true.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

\newread\file
\def\@gobblethree#1#2#3{}
\newcommand\myaccumulatedfile{}
\long\def\aegobbleinput#1{%
  \IfFileExists{#1}{%
    \openin\file #1
    \begingroup
    \endlinechar\newlinechar
    \loop\unless\ifeof\file
      \readline\file to\foo
%<a>%     \edef\myaccumulatedfile{\myaccumulatedfile\expandafter\@aegobble\foo\@nil}%%
%<b>%     \aftergroup\edef\myaccumulatedfile{\myaccumulatedfile\expandafter\@aegobble\foo\@nil}%%
    \repeat
    \closein\file
    \expandafter\endgroup
    \scantokens\expandafter{\myaccumulatedfile}
  }{%
    \errmessage{File `#1' doesn't exist!}%
  }%
}

\def\@aegobble{%%'
  \@ifnextchar*{\@@aegobble}{\@@nogobble}%%'
}

\def\@@aegobble*#1\@nil{Star}
\def\@@nogobble#1\@nil{#1Major}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

Try:

\aegobbleinput{test_file/star_test}

\end{document}
```

As written, this MWE will compile, but I've commented out the crucial lines.

If the line starting with `%<a>%` is uncommented, then I get the fatal error

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\foo ->
         The character of the First Caesar has perhaps never been worse
l.7 \aegobbleinput{test_file/star_test}
                                       ^^M
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

If the line starting with `%<b>%` is uncommented, then I get the non-fatal error

```
Runaway definition?
\edef \edef \edef \edef \edef \edef \edef \edef 
! File ended while scanning definition of \edef.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.7 \aegobbleinput{test_file/star_test}

?
```

This last approach seems somewhat correct.  At least the produced pdf is approaching something like what I want.

What am I doing wrong here?

**UPDATE**

Per @jfbu 's suggestion, the following seems to work:

```
\makeatletter
\newif\ifaeshowall
\aeshowallfalse
\long\gdef\aegobbleinput#1{%%'
  \begingroup
  \ifaeshowall\catcode`\*=9\relax\else\catcode`\*=14\relax\fi
  \input{#1}\endgroup}
\makeatother
```

Comment: It the `*` is reserved for use as the first character of lines to be possibly omitted, why  don't you do `\catcode\`\*=14\relax` (resp. `\catcode\`\*=9\relax`) to let it act as a comment character (resp. be ignored), just before inputting the file via `\input` (or variants)?

Comment: @jfbu That's part of my problem.... finding a character that I can reserve for the first character of a line.  Though your suggestion of changing the catcode for this character is not one I had thought of.

Comment: @jfbu That works beautifully!!!  If you post that as an answer I would accept.

Comment: @jfbu So, probably a better character than `*` would be `"` since for the documents I'm working with `"` is extremely unlikely to show up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, and switching to using `"` rather than `*`, or any other character strictly reserved to use in the input files as a label of lines possibly to be omitted, the suggestion is to do something like this:

```
\def\doublequotecommentsout {\catcode`\"=14\relax}
\def\doublequoteisignored   {\catcode`\"=9\relax }
\def\makedoublequoteother   {\catcode`\"=12\relax }
```

and then wrap up the `\input` command, or `\InputIfFileExists` inside the desired commands.

In some languages, Babel makes `"` active, and the suitable Babel commands (`\shorthandoff`,`\shorthandon`) should be used rather than the above, or rather one should choose another character not playing a rôle in that language as shorthand character.

Comment: Is it possible to assign catcodes to tokens?  For example, would it be possible to do something like `\catcode\myspecialtoken=14\relax` etc.?

Comment: @A.Ellett No, control sequences like `\myspecialtoken` already have a catcode of sorts (internally for TeX, not one you can alter). You can only set the catcode for a character.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is tricky to spot as the error isn't very helpful in the first case and gives little away in the second! You have two underlying issues. First, `\@ifnextchar` is not expandable (cannot be used inside an `\edef` or similar). There is an assignment (`\futurelet`) inside `\@ifnextchar`, and this simply doesn't happen inside `\edef`. You can define an expandable variant of `\@ifnextchar` with some limitations (you have to grab one token, so it can go wrong if there is for example 'nothing to see'). The second problem is that `\aftergroup` inserts exactly one token after the group, not lots of tokens. Thus `\aftergroup\edef\myaccumulatedfile` inserts one `\edef` after the group for each line of the file, and then just plonks `\myaccumulatedfile` into the input 'now'. This approach is not even worth fixing as `\foo` will be reset after the group anyway, so you will never get out what you are after.